# In PyCharm, how do you import a project as a whole (not only its modules) from another one?

Tags: python, pycharm, dependencies, project

I have two projects: `project_main`, `utils`

Anywhere in project_main, I would like to do
`from utils import ua, ub`

It is the same problem that has been answered here
[In PyCharm, how do you add a directory from one project as a source to another project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39648578/in-pycharm-how-do-you-add-a-directory-from-one-project-as-a-source-to-another-p)

But it only allows me to do
`import ua, ub`
and not what i wish
`from utils import ua, ub`

I have looked for project structure, project dependencies but did not find anything.
Is is possible ? thx :)

Comment: share project structure, cant tell without it

Comment: There are 2 environments, one where project_main and utils are at same level, and the second they are far away. Wherever is utils I would like project_main to be able to import it

Comment: on pycharm you can add utils as included folder, so your pycharm know this is part of prpoject